# How to add Laravel Web Application on Facebook TAB

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5, error-handling, laravel-5.4

I am working with Laravel 5.4.

1) I add the Website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJtAZ.png)

and all it's okay for the moment.

2) Try to open the website on facebook, got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lguS7.png)

> W*hoops, looks like something went wrong.*
>
> **1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233**
>
> *Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:*
>
> 1. in RouteCollection.php line 233
> 2. at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 220
> 3. at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
> 4. at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
> 5. at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
> 6. at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
> 7. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
> 8. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
> 9. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
> 10. at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> 11. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> 12. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
> 13. at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> 14. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> 15. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
> 16. at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> 17. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> 18. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
> 19. at Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request),
>       object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
> 20. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
> 21. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
> 22. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
> 23. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
> 24. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is only thrown when attempting to access a route with the wrong http verb.

E.g. attempting to access a POST route with a GET request.

Comment: Thx, i add new route with post method.